# do i have an image processor to compare an image with a number of images and choose the identical image??

Tags: image-processing

I require an image processor which compares an image with a set of images and finds the equivalent image out of them.

Comment: Have you done anything to find or create that image processor?

Comment: Nope!! am a mere beginner and i have no clue on how to go about it

Comment: Your problem is not well defined. What do you mean by "equivalent"? Are you looking for exactly the same images (i.e. to filter out duplicate pictures from a large library) or do you need to detect duplicates that have somehow be distorted (e.g. noise, cropping, rotation, translation, scaling)?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question and to be honest there are a multitude of ways to go about this. I highly recommend that you read more into imaging processing literature in general. From this you could perhaps suggest an approach that we could base our answers on, and help hone in on a good method for you.

That being said, a common approach to your problem is the SIFT algorithm. This algorithm will give back a set of features for a given image. From this you could construct a way to recognise images. However, this might not be the simplest solution if you are just a beginner at this game.

Best of luck!